Checking defined indexes in Azure CosmosDB
I'm currently expanding an existing system, where I need a new query on a container "Parts" that has ~3 million documents. I'm using the following query to look for all documents, that contains an item in the "parts" array, with partNumber "ABC12345":
// 69 RUs small test
SELECT c.partNumber 
FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.parts, { 'partNumber': 'ABC12345'}, true)

This query is very slow. For some parameters, it will take a few seconds, taking up ~100 RU's, but on more often occurring matches this will take much much longer, and thousands of RU's. This is a problem. This testing has been done using the Azure Portal, if that makes a difference.
I've first tried optimize the queries, but this did not improve performance. I've been researching this and contrary to my initial understanding of CosmosDB, arrays are not indexed by default. Hence, I've added an index to the property partNumber, in hopes to optimize performance, as follows:
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        },
        {
            "path": "/parts/[]/partNumber/?"
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        }
    ]
}

However, I'm not seeing any improvement in performance. How can I verify the index is properly defined; is there a way to "browse" the CosmosDB indexes so I can make sure I've set this up correctly and that the index is being used correctly?
I would first like to verify this before I start pursuing alternative solutions.

You haven't mentioned anything about how you partitioned your container. It's possible that you're seeing a cross-partition query. Also, try directly querying via code, and being explicit about choosing partition key value vs cross-partition query + continuations.

The value field partNumber on the parts array should already be indexed, as all fields are indexed unless you specifically exclude them.
I think your actual issue is the use of ARRAY_CONTAINS with true passed as the last parameter (partial_match). In my experience, this tends to result in a full collection scan regardless of indexes. It's logically equivalent to functions such as string CONTAINS when partial match is true, which don't play nicely with indexes.
Instead of ARRAY_CONTAINS, I believe you can express your query with a join and an equality clause, which should hit the index.
SELECT
  c.partNumber
FROM
  c
JOIN
  p IN c.parts
WHERE
  p.partNumber = 'ABC12345'

